# Installation Blocked running Android Application

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm doing updates to one of my apps on a Galaxy S6 that has Marshmallow.  Almost every time I run the application through Android Studio I get a "Installation blocked" dialog that I have to click "Install anyway (unsafe)" so that it will install.  I'm not aware of why it is saying the app is unsafe nor do I understand how to keep this from popping up.  Is there a work around for this or is there a way to find out what it is complaining about?

[image: example of dialog from http://www.techmash.in/2016/04/how-to-root-android-mobile-without-pc.html]

This is an example image from [here](http://www.techmash.in/2016/04/how-to-root-android-mobile-without-pc.html) and not my application.

Comment: I recommend that you post a screenshot somewhere of this dialog, then link to it from your question, and indicate the make and model of the device. Also, by "run the application", do you mean running it from an IDE? Or what exactly are your steps that you take that trigger the dialog?

Comment: If you are updating(installing) the app with sd card or with adb it will show this. If you want to install non market apps you should allow Settings > Security > Unknown Sources. If that is not a case the update app may be harmful. You can Bypass the dialog by Settings > Security > Verify apps  or Settings > Developer options > Verify apps over USB.

Comment: Considering that the application is called "RootMaster", I'm guessing that is requires root permission on your device, therefore is being blocked

Comment: @AjithPandian disabling Verify apps over USB did the trick.  If you want to put it as an answer I'll except it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are updating(installing) the app with sd card or with adb it will show this. If you want to install non market apps you should allow Settings > Security > Unknown Sources. If that is not a case the update app may be harmful. You can Bypass the dialog by Settings > Security > Verify apps or Settings > Developer options > Verify apps over USB

Answer (score 0):

Try going to 
File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > disable all checkBoxes
and also try cleaning your project
hope this helps